How can I convert a voltage signal from a breadboard into an audio signal?
I have a personal project of mine where I am converting an audio signal (.wav file) to a voltage signal and similarly a voltage signal into an audio signal. I was able to do the former using an aux cable and simply reading the values on oscilloscope but I have no idea on how to do the latter.
I would prefer if there was any way to do it using my laptop as most laptops do have the sound cards and amplifiers necessary to do so.

Audio signals are already voltage signals. But not all voltage signal are audio signals if they are not audio. And you can measure any voltage signal with an oscilloscope. So please refine what you really want to do or ask.

First let's get our terminology straight, we'll call the voltage the audio signal, and the stored digital representation of the voltage an audio file.
It sounds like what you want to do is convert an audio signal to an audio file in WAV format and vice-versa. This is digital recording and playback.
Converting an audio file to an audio signal with a computer just requires using a software player that will handle the file format (WAV, MP3, FLAC, etc.) to play the file, and then taking the signal from the sound card output.
Likewise you can convert an audio signal to an audio file by connecting the signal to the sound card input and using appropriate software to encode the signal to an audio file. You need to be mindful of voltages and impedances as it is possible to damage your sound card if you connect it to the wrong thing.
Inputs and outputs are going to vary by sound card, they may have microphone and line inputs and various speaker, headphone and line level outputs. You would need to know which ones your equipment has and how to interface to them properly.
Then you would need to choose software to do the encoding and decoding depending on which format you want. Typically computers come with some sort of basic audio player and recorder software which will usually do WAV format. Alternatively you could look for other software to do what you want.
